# Why isn't the background showing up in my footer?

Tags: html, css

So I've given my footer a background colour but it's not showing up so I want to know what the right code is?? Here is my html code:

```css
.footer {
  background-color: #D4D4D4;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: #d4d4d4;">
  <footer style="background-color: #d4d4d4;">
    <div style="position:relative;background-color:#d4d4d4" class="footer">
      <div style="position: absolute; left:1%">
        <p style="font-size: 10pt;"><img src='images/DBA LOGO.png ' width="30" height="30" align="left" style="display: inline-block;">DIGITAL BUCKET COMPANY</p>
      </div>
      <div style="position: absolute; left:20%">
        <h3>Pages</h3>
        <p>Link</p>
        <p>Link</p>
        <p>Link</p>
        <p>Link</p>
      </div>
      <div style="position: absolute; left:50%">
        <h3>Pages</h3>
        <p>Link</p>
        <p>Link</p>
        <p>Link</p>
        <p>Link</p>

      </div>
      <div style="position: absolute; left:80%">
        <h3>Pages</h3>
        <p>Link</p>
        <p>Link</p>
        <p>Link</p>
        <p>Link</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Here is what it looks like: [image]

I also want the image and text to be in line.

Answer (score 1):

Your footer takes no space as everything inside it is absolutely positioned (which means the element is removed from the normal flow of the document).  I would make the footer flex, and then remove the absolute positioning:

```css
.footer {
  background-color: #D4D4D4;
  display: flex;
}

.logo {
  width: 20%;
}

.column {
  width: 27%;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: #d4d4d4;">
  <footer style="background-color: #d4d4d4;">
    <div style="position:relative;background-color:#d4d4d4" class="footer">
      <div class="logo">
        <p style="font-size: 10pt;"><img src='images/DBA LOGO.png ' width="30" height="30" align="left" style="display: inline-block;">DIGITAL BUCKET COMPANY</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <h3>Pages</h3>
        <p>Link</p>
        <p>Link</p>
        <p>Link</p>
        <p>Link</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <h3>Pages</h3>
        <p>Link</p>
        <p>Link</p>
        <p>Link</p>
        <p>Link</p>

      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <h3>Pages</h3>
        <p>Link</p>
        <p>Link</p>
        <p>Link</p>
        <p>Link</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you make position of a div absolute, it is removed from the normal flow of the page, so parent does not know itself size, so you have to define size manually.your footer class should be like this:

```
.footer {
  background-color: #D4D4D4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px
}
```